# filepicker _field changes to link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, filepicker.io, filepicker

this is my code

```
<div class="form-group">
    <%= user.label :img,"Profile Picture",:class => "col-sm-3 control-label" %>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
         <%= user.filepicker_field :img, accept: 'image/jpeg,image/gif,image/png' , class: 'btn btn-default btn-lg btn-warning center-block', :button_text => "Select Image"%>
    </div>
</div>
```

and it sometimes when i am trying to reload the page the button text changes from "Select Image" to link !
[image: problem example]

How can i fix that ??

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you assigning the blob.url to the image tag attribute.